# Delayed::Job with modules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Does Delayed::Job work with modules? 
I have trouble with it:

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
     def regular_method
       self.delay.long_method "test"
     end

     def long_method data
       puts data
     end
  end
end
```

Error message:

```
[Worker(host:leo pid:10480)] SomeModule::SomeClass#long_method failed with NoMethodError: undefined method `long_method' for #<YAML::Object:0xcee13b0 @class="SomeModule::SomeClass", @ivars={}> - 4 failed attempts
[Worker(host:leo pid:10480)] 1 jobs processed at 9.1484 j/s, 1 failed ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem in rails class auto loading. Just add

```
require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/some_module/some_class"
```

to initializers or environment.rb